# Show that there is at least one real value of x for which $x^\frac{3}2 + x^\frac{1}2 =1$

Tags: calculus, continuity

**QUESTION:** Show that there is atleast one real value of x for which $x^\frac{3}2+ x^\frac{1}2 =1$

**MY APPROACH:** Let $x=z^2.$
Then we can rewrite the equation as $z^3+z-1=0.$

Now, this is clearly a cubic equation and if we assume that z is real then this equation must have atleast one real root (by the concept of complex conjugate theorem). Therefore, for real $z$, we have atleast one real value of $x$ and therefore, by this simple argument we can come to the conclusion that the equation is true for atleast one real value of $x$.

My question is, I am not sure that my reasoning is correct or not. This question has been asked before, but the way it was solved is different. I just want to know if I have done it correctly or not.
Thank you.

(I did not find quite relevant tags for this question, any suggestions are welcome).

Comment: I think you also need $z>0$.

Comment: But $x=z^2$ , so $x$ is always positive no matter what the value of $z$ is..

Comment: Angina. Even if $z<0$, $x=z^2 >0$, no problem, do I miss something?

Comment: Stranger. I think your argument is fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Angina points out, it's a priori possible that the cubic has a negative real root, which would be a problem for your argument.

The cleanest way to solve problems like this is usually the Intermediate Value Theorem, which states: if $f(x)$ is continuous on $[a,b]$, then for each $y$ between $f(a)$ and $f(b)$, there is some $c\in (a,b)$ such that $f(c)=y$. In particular, if $f(a)$ and $f(b)$ have opposite signs, then $f$ has a root in $(a,b)$, i.e. $f(c)=0$ for some $c$. With your problem, we have $f(x)=x^{3/2}+x^{1/2}-1$. $f$ is continuous on $[0,1]$ and $f(0)=-1,$ $f(1)=1$.

Comment: Yes, it is true that a cubic polynomial may have a negative root, but since $x=z^2$ therefore, $x$ will be positive for any value of $z$.. now does the argument still remain faulty?

Answer (score 2):

$$0^{3/2}+0^{1/2}<1$$ and $$1^{3/2}+1^{1/2}>1.$$

By continuity there must be an intermediate value which solves the equation.